# Clicking on button using python + selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, cookies

I access the website called iens with chrome using selenium in python. I want my script to click on "Volgende" (which means "Next" in dutch), to move to the next page. However, I get the following error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error:
Element is not clickable at point (853, 667). Other element would 
receive the click: <div class="cookiePolicy-content">...</div>
```

I presume something is going wrong regarding the cookies that pop up when selenium enters the website. So far I haven't been able to find out what I can do to move past the cookies.

My code thus far:

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_path = '/Users/username/Downloads/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get('https://www.iens.nl/restaurant+utrecht')

link = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Volgende")
link.click()
```

This is the website: https://www.iens.nl/restaurant+utrecht

Comment: if you look at the message it says the cookie policy message will receive the click event, because even when selenium attempts to scroll the Volgende button into view, the cookie policy message will be floating over the button and so it won't be clickable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is due to the cookie floating footer at the bottom. Selenium will scroll your button into view, but it doesn't realize that it needs to scroll it above the cookie floating div.

I'd suggest either clicking on the close button on the cookie message or scrolling the element out from behind the cookie message.

To close the cookie, you're going to want to click the close and wait for it to disappear:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


chrome_path = '/Users/username/Downloads/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get('https://www.iens.nl/restaurant+utrecht')

# Wait for cookie message
close_icon = WebDriverWait(driver, 5, 0.25).until(ec.visibility_of_element_located([By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.cookiePolicy-close']))
close_icon.click()
# Wait for cookie message to disappear
WebDriverWait(driver, 5, 0.25).until(ec.invisibility_of_element_located([By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.cookiePolicy-close']))
link = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Volgende")
link.click()
```

To scroll the element from behind the cookie message:

EDIT: It appears this page also has a floating top header, so you actually can't just scroll it to the top of the page either... You need to scroll it out from behind the cookie message.

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_path = '/Users/username/Downloads/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get('https://www.iens.nl/restaurant+utrecht')

link = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Volgende")
# Scroll to element as Selenium would
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(false);', link)
# Then scroll it up to get it out from behind the message
driver.execute_script('window.scrollBy(0, 200)')
link.click()
```

Edit: I've confirmed both of these options work

Comment: Thank you so much! If it's not too much time for you; how would I write a loop that clicks on next page until the program is at the last page?

Comment: Do you need it to cycle through each page? Or do you just want to get to the last page? There's a link right next to the 'next' button for the last page

Comment: If you need to cycle through the pages, you should be able to do it by putting everything under `driver.get` in a while loop... `while 'disabled' not in driver.find_element_by_css_selector('li.next').get_attribute('class'):`

Comment: I'm sorry I can't figure it out just yet. I added the while below the WebDriverWait(driver, 5, 0.25).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located([By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.cookiePolicy-close'])) since there are no cookies after you click on next page. However, I get an error when I'm at page 3. It says "element is not attachted to the page document."

Comment: There's going to be some timing issues since it's handled by javascript. The best I can do is to suggest adding this after `link.click()`:

`WebDriverWait(driver, 5, 0.25).until(ec.visibility_of_element_located([By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'li.next']))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of `driver_find_element_by_link_text()`:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pagination_results"]/div/div/ul/li[14]/a');
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium tries to simulate real user behavior. That means it can click only on visible elements. You need to bring the element into view in order to click on it

```
link = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Volgende")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(link).perform()
link.click()
```

Comment: Selenium will automatically scroll the element into the viewport before clicking on it. The problem he is having is that it is behind a floating element which Selenium will not account for